# build Grails 3 war with specific java compiler version

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, gradle

I am using IDEA 15. I have a grails 3 project setup. The app server I need to deploy to has Java Version 7. My local JDK is Java 8. I have set some properties in my build.gradle to use the target version 1.7.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
compileJava {
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
}
```

When I rebuild my project, it generates class files for 1.7, but when I run a maven war build from the IDEA menu, the classes are rebuilt and end up being Java 8 versions. I have set Java version in my project to 1.7 as well, but this did not help. How can I get to where I am producing a war file from my grails app that contains 1.7 versioned class files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to build war file? "grails war" or "gradle war".  Try to use gradle.